# how to get table name

Tags: sql, oracle

i have additional table for saving history of edits. i want to do trigger for that and i need to save table name, where changes were made. how can i get a table name?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DELDATA
AFTER DELETE
ON STUDENT
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    nextdata NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT sn.nextval into nextdata FROM DUAL d;
    INSERT INTO STUDENTDEL(id, sn, TABLENAME)
    values(:OLD.id, NEXTDATA, 'table_name');
END;
```

Comment: mb i need to use :OLD.___ for that?

Comment: As the trigger is defined for the table `STUDENT` and you can't re-use that trigger definition for anything else, just put `'STUDENT'` in there

Comment: Note that `SELECT sn.nextval into nextdata FROM DUAL d;` can be simplified to `nextdata := sn.nextval`. Or you can use `sn.nextval` directly in the VALUES part and get rid of the variable completely.

Comment: but if i want to use it for some tables? can i use only one trigger. not own trigger for every table

Comment: i need analog of TG_TABLE_NAME from postrgres. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: You can't use the same trigger for multiple tables in Oracle. That's why there is no equivalent to TG_TABLE_NAME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no equivalent, because we can't use the same trigger for multiple table in Oracle